# Как выполнить условие при определенном ответе alert

Tags: javascript, php, html

Мне нужно разблокировать div в зависимости от ответа в alert.

Вот мой скрипт который выполняет php файл и возвращает alert.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
    
$('#podt').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();    
    $.post('/inc/test_code_sms.php', $('#form1').serialize(),function (data){
    alert(data);
        if alert("Номер активирован") {     
            let content = document.getElementById("content")



content.style.display = "block" }
        
   });         
    });
     });
</script>
```

Вот сам php файл.

```
   <?php
//  Проверка кода

    if (isset($_POST["recipient"]) && isset($_POST["code"])) {
        $i=0;
//  Открываем "file.txt" в режиме чтения
        $fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"); 
        if ($fp){
            while (!feof($fp)){
                $mytext = fgets($fp);
                $array[$i]=trim($mytext);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $arr=$array;
        fclose($fp);
        $recipient = $_POST['recipient']; 
        $key = array_search($recipient, $arr);
        $code=$arr[$key+1];   
        $phoneex=$arr[$key];    
            if ($code == $_POST["code"] && $phoneex==$_POST["recipient"]){ 
        
                echo "Номер активирован";
    
    //  Удаление номера с кодом из файла
                $file=file("file.txt");
                $fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($file);$i++){    
                    if($i==$key){
                        unset($file[$i]);
                        unset($file[$i+1]);
                    }
                }
                fputs($fp,implode("",$file));
                fclose($fp);
                
            

    
            
                
            // Тут нужно остановить выполнение кода
            }else{


                echo( "Неверный номер или код подтверждения" );
                

                 }
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Во-первых  Js код невалиден. Во-вторых - пробелма не ясна. .............. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `if (data == "Номер активирован")`

Comment: Так а зачем проверять так `if alert("Номер активирован")`? Во-первых нет скобок у `if`, а во-вторых, таким образом вы вызываете функцию `alert`, а в if попадает ее результат, т.е. `undefined`, поэтому у вас блок никогда не откроется. Вы с сервера возвращаете результат и записываете его в `data`, так и проверяйте `data`

Comment: Я просто не очень понимаю как правильно мне оформить if с данным условием. 
Я пробовал встроить разблокировку div в сам php но у меня тогда выводится код скрипта в alert, поэтому я решил попробовать сделать разблокировку в зависимости от ответа.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста что еще нужно подправить


`if (data("Номер активирован")) {  
    let content = document.getElementById("content")
    
   content.style.display = "block" };   }); }); });`

Comment: Повторяю `if (data == "Номер активирован")`: сравниваем значение переменной `data` со строкой `"Номер активирован"`.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо большое!!!